# Windows crash report pop up 3 times when Windows XP starts after updating IE7 to IE8

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, windows-update

I just updated Internet Explorer 7 to IE 8. After the reboot, I have the Windows XP "send error report" dialog 3 times all with this info in it:

```
AppName: update_kb24b8.exe  AppVer: 7.0.6000.16981  ModName: urlmon.dll
ModVer: 8.0.6001.18904  Offset: 0002df76
```

I uninstalled/updated all of my plugins and I still have this error 3 times each time I log in.

Anyone know what is **update_kb24b8.exe** I didn't found a Microsoft KB with this number...

BTW, after these 3 errors, everything s working well, including IE...

**UPDATE:** The file in question is located here:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft_KB57H43\Update_KB24B8.exe

What is **KB57H43**? Can't find anything on MS website...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help?:

["Invalid Page Fault in Module Urlmon.dll" Error Message When Starting Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254490)

Blurb:

> This behavior can occur if there are multiple entries for QuickView Plus in the registry.

---

**Edit:**

OK I dug deeper into this.

The update_kb24b8.exe didn't turn anything up, but the folder name (Microsoft_KB57H43) gave it away.  So it sounds like you, my friend, are infected with a variant of the Spy-Net RAT ([Remote Administration Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration_tool)).

[Here's the tutorial](http://spynetrat.blogspot.com/) on how to set it up that gave it away via Google (which also mentions renaming the Microsoft_KB57H43 folder to something else, apparently the person who built your Spy-Net RAT variant didn't use that tutorial :) ).

Get yourself some anti-malware utilities and scan your computer.  I'd say try [HitMan Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro), and [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) first.  Check out this other SU question/wiki on some general anti-malware information - "[What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)"

Getting rid of this may not fix your problem, as it may be caused by invalid links and associations to the Spy-Net stuff (that become/became invalid when/if spy-net was removed).

Also, the malicious user out there (controlling your RAT install) may have used it to infect you further with other malware.

Seeing what that RAT can do, I'd ensure it was clean (even if I had to reformat to feel sure), and then start going and changing my passwords everywhere, hopefully *before* my bank account was emptied and my credit was ruined. :)

Comment: Unfortunately not... Checked my registry and the key is not there. BTW the KB you linked seems only to apply to IE5 under Win98SE.

Comment: Edited my answer with new malware-related info.

Comment: This was indeed (many) trojans! I don't know how I got infected. It's my workstation at work and we have an antivirus that we can't even shutdown. MalwareBytes fixed this and I notified our admin that their antivirus is full of holes :) I just hope our firewall didn't let something in/out on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the upgrade/IE8. After that, do a clean with CCleaner. After that, grab Internet Explorer from Microsoft download center and install it like that. (Just an idea, but it may worth a try.)